# Making an image inside a figure a link - image size changes

Tags: html, image, flexbox, anchor, figure

Hi when I wrap my image with a anchor the image itself becomes really small. I have the image inside of a figure and I am using flex-box, I am not really sure how to keep the image size from changing.

```css
.foo{
display:flex;
flex-direction:row;
justify-content:space-around;
}
```

```html
<figure class="foo">
<a href="#"><img src="#"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="#"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="#"></a>
</figure>
```

Comment: Please post enough code to reproduce the problem (e.g. include the images).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here how i solved,

```css
.foo{
display:flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
margin-left: 20px;
width: calc(100% + 20px);
}

.foo a{
flex: 1 1 280px;
margin-left: 20px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.foo a img{
width:100%
height: auto;
}
```

```html
<figure class="foo">
<a href="#"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE5lz.png"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE5lz.png"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE5lz.png"></a>
</figure>
```

```css
.foo{
display:flex;
flex-direction:row;
justify-content:space-around;
}
```

```html
<figure class="foo">
<a href="#"><img src="#"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="#"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="#"></a>
</figure>
```

```css
.foo{
display:flex;
flex-direction:row;
justify-content:space-around;
}

.foo img{
height:100px;
width:100px;
}
```

```html
<figure class="foo">
<a href="#"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE5lz.png"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE5lz.png"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE5lz.png"></a>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add css for `img` tags for inside `foo` class. This gave `100px` height and width for each `img`.

```css
.foo{
display:flex;
flex-direction:row;
justify-content:space-around;
}

.foo img{
height:100px;
width:100px;
}
```

```html
<figure class="foo">
<a href="#"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE5lz.png"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE5lz.png"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE5lz.png"></a>
</figure>
```